# Element does nit selected inb select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, dropdown

```js
        $ajax.select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "/TestSelect2DropDown/GetCountries",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;

                    return {
                        results: data.result.items,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * 30) < data.result.totalCount
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            templateResult: formatRepo,
            templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
        });

        function formatRepo(repo) {
            if (repo.loading) return repo.displayText;

            var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
                "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.displayText + "</div>";
            if (repo.displayText) {
                markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.displayText + "</div>";
            }
            markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
            "</div></div>";
            return markup;
        }

        function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
            return repo.displayText;
        }
```

```html
            <select class="js-example-data-ajax form-control">
                <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
            </select>
```

I try to get data with ajax in select2 drop down. I get data but when I try to select an element it does nit be selected. And this drop has no scroll to show data in other pages.
There is any idea to solve this problems?

Comment: your question is vague, your data is countries right and you want to show countries in dropdown? and you can not select those countries?

Comment: @WasifKhan my data is countries and I want to show countries in dropdown; but I can not select those countries.

Comment: can you make plnkr example of it?

Comment: @WasifKhan Excute me, what is plnkr example? I copy this example from select2 web site

Comment: try looking to this example. Plnkr is very important tool to share code online. 
http://embed.plnkr.co/kxs4Rl/